# Fullcalendar drag / drop on different background event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar and i can resize and replace events on the same background event, but i would like to drag/drop events on to other background events.

This currently does not work because i get an stop sign on my cursor.
It would really appreciable if someone helps to achieve this. Thankyou in advance.

```
    editable: true,
                        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    var id  = event.id;
                    var start = event.start;
                    var end = event.end;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'update.php',
                        data:
                            {   updatetype: "resetdate",
                                token: "ahdghdghdghdghdghdghdghdgh",
                                start: (new Date(start).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0),
                                end: (new Date(end).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0),
                                event_id: id
                            },
                        type: 'POST'
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
        businessHours: true, // display business hours
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Business Lunch',
                start: '2015-02-03T13:00:00',
                constraint: 'businessHours' //define constraint id here
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-02-13T11:00:00',
                constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
                color: '#257e4a'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2015-02-18',
                end: '2015-02-20'
            },
            {
                title: 'Party',
                start: '2015-02-29T20:00:00'
            },

            // areas where (your defined) "Meeting" must be dropped adjust as per your requirement
            {
                id: 'availableForMeeting',
                start: '2015-02-11T10:00:00',
                end: '2015-02-11T16:00:00',
                rendering: 'background'
            },
            {
                id: 'availableForMeeting',
                start: '2015-02-13T10:00:00',
                end: '2015-02-13T16:00:00',
                rendering: 'background'
            },

            // red areas where no events can be dropped
            {
                start: '2015-02-24',
                end: '2015-02-28',
                overlap: true, //make true so you can drag and drop event on background as well
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89'
            },
            {
                start: '2015-02-06',
                end: '2015-02-08',
                overlap: true,
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89'
            }
        ]
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this is working.
But i would also like to get the classname like "class="fc-bgevent background_831716"" from the new background event.
Is this possible?